# Websphere application server 8.5.5 clustering same application

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

I have the same application running on two WAS clusters.  Each cluster has 3 application servers based in different datacenters.  In front of each cluster are 3 IHS servers.

Can I specify a primary cluster, and a failover cluster within the plugin-cfg.xml?  Currently I have both clusters defined within the plugin, but I'm only hitting 1 cluster for every request.  The second cluster is completely ignored.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted already the WAS HTTP server plugin doesn't provide the function your're seeking as documented in the WAS KC http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rwsv_plugincfg.html?lang=en
assuming that by "failover cluster" what is actually meant is "BackupServers" in the plugin-cfg.xml

The ODR alternative mentioned previously likely isn't an option either, this because the ODR isn't supported for use in the DMZ (it's not been security hardened for DMZ deployment) http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/twve_odoecreateodr.html?lang=en

From an effective HA/DR perspective what you're seeking to accomplish should handled at the network layer, using the global load balancer (global site selector, global traffic manager, etc) that is routing traffic into the data centers, this is usually accomplished by setting a "site cookie" using the load balancer

Answer (score 0):

This is by design. IHS, at least at the 8.5.5 level, does not allow for what you are trying to do. You will have to implement such level of high availability in a higher level in your topology.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options.

If the environemnt is relatively static, you could post-process plugin-cfg.xml and combine them into a single ServerCluster with the "dc2" servers listed as <BackupServer>'s in the cluster.  The "dc1" servers are probably already listed as <PrimaryServer>'s

BackupServers are only used when no PrimaryServers are reachable.

Another option is to use the Java On-Demand Router, which has first-class awareness of applications running in two cells.  Rules can be written that dictate the behavior of applications residing in two clusters (load balancer, failover, etc.).  I believe these are "ODR Routing Rules".